# Why does adding this protocol to this category trigger a compiler warning?

Tags: objective-c

In my code I have the following compiler warning:

```
Initializing 'MyClass *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type '__strong id<MyProtocol>'
```

My question is this, why does the compiler warning go away if I remove the protocol  from the category?

As in, when when I replace

```
@interface MyClass (CategoryNameHere) <SomeOtherProtocol>
```

With

```
@interface MyClass (CategoryNameHere)
```

I have found minimal piece of code which reproduces this scenario:

```
@interface MyWidget ()
@end

@protocol MyProtocol
@end

@protocol SomeOtherProtocol
@end


@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>
@end

@interface MyClass (CategoryNameHere) <SomeOtherProtocol>
@end


@implementation MyWidget

- (MyClass *)sampleMethod:(id<MyProtocol>)v {
  MyClass *instance = v;
  return instance;
}

@end
```

The compiler warning is on the line which contains

```
MyClass *instance = v;
```

Comment: "It said that it can't find a way in a graph of types which satisfy rules of type casting". Simple: id<SomeProtocol> is a pointer to generic Objective-C object which satisfy protocol <SomeProtocol>. It is not a (MyClass *) pointer, it is more generic.

Comment: Though, that is true even before adding the protocol to the category, yet there there is no compiler warning before adding the protocol. Why does the compiler warning exist only after adding this <SomeOtherProtocol> protocol?

Comment: It's almost as if SomeOtherProtocol overrides MyProtocol and MyProtocol gets completely ignored.

(Though technically, this compiler warning appears like it should always be present, but it is not).

Comment: I think that it is a trick of compiler. It considers `Base` as a generic class. ( It doesn't have superclass ). Thus, it has definition as id<MyProtocol>. But when you add additional protocol, it treats it as id<MyProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol>.

Comment: That is a great thought gaussblurinc. Though if I were to add methods to the class that are not part of the protocol it should make this potential optimization go away since the class != protocol at that point. Though adding methods to the class doesn't make this behave any differently. (Also adding an additional super class as you mentioned seems to also not change the behavior)

Comment: I am leaning towards this being a bug in the objc compiler warning implementation since it's sometimes letting me put id<MyProtocol> into an instance of MyClass. Though it sounds like a really common case, so that's odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
@interface Factory : NSObject @end

@protocol First @end
@protocol Second @end
@protocol Third @end

@interface Base <First, Second> @end
@interface Custom : Base @end

@interface Base (CategoryNameHere) <Second>
@end

@implementation Factory

- (Custom *)sampleMethod:(id<First, Second>)v {
    return v;
}

@end
```

Consider example that you have provided with several renaming.

You can play with it by adding/removing protocols as requirement for `Factory`'s method or by adding/removing protocols as extensions for classes.

The corner stone of this example is bare ( without superclass ) class `Base`.

It is considered as `id<First, Second>` by compiler.